# 'firebase.firestore is not a function' when using in react-native expo

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I am trying to use Firestore in the react-native expo. But getting the error 'firebase.firestore is not a function', even there are many solutions on the internet; I could not get it to work.

https://snack.expo.io/@karthikeyan.live/firebase-error

I confirmed importing 'firebase' and 'firebase/firestore'

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import "firebase/firestore"
...
var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: '',
      authDomain: '',
      databaseURL: '',
      projectId: '',
      storageBucket: '',
      messagingSenderId: '',
      appId: '',
    };
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

var firestore = firebase.firestore()
```

Below is the screenshot of the error 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use the react-native firebase wrapper (https://rnfirebase.io/) and i would do like this:

```
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
var ref = firebase.firestore().collection('todos');
```

Comment: Same error occurs even if I use 'react-native-firebase'
https://snack.expo.io/@karthikeyan.live/firebase-error

Comment: @Karthikeyan that's true that in the doc, they advise to eject the app (by linking and all)

Answer (score 0):

1. `import 'firebase/firestore';` is useless. Remove that.
2. You are invoking `onPressLearnMore` function

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
          <Button
            onPress={this.onPressLearnMore()}
            title="Click"
            color="#841584"
            accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
          />
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Change it to:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
          <Button
            onPress={this.onPressLearnMore}
            title="Click"
            color="#841584"
            accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
          />
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work either. The same error occurs.

Comment: Here is the error [https://pasteboard.co/IsBqtmx.png](https://pasteboard.co/IsBqtmx.png)

Comment: What node module are you using for firebase?

Comment: I am using this. "firebase": "6.3.5"